# java.io package in Camel can not find file with special character in its title

Tags: utf-8, java-8, apache-camel, special-characters, java-io

I am looking over an issue with a Java (v1.8.0_192-b12) application which is using Apache Camel (v2.22.1) to poll files from a folder. Everything works fine with files that do not have special characters in their title, but when a file contains characters like *Å*, strange behavior occurs:

- camel is outputting the file name with ?? - it cannot print the actual character
- when testing file size it returns 0
- if I manage to bypass the two points above, then the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is thrown

I have managed so solve the first two points by shadowing one of Camel's class and replacing the `java.io` package with `java.nio`, but still did not manage to fix the behavior entirely. **So, at this point, it seems that java.io has a bug which java.nio solved.** In other words, the file is retrieved, but afterwords, when trying to execute actions on it, it fails (it can no more locate it by its name).
Initial code - which returned files that failed afterwords when were processed:

```
File directory = new File(fileName);
File[] dirFiles = directory.listFiles();
```

The working code:

```
Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(fileName))
File[] dirFiles = stream.map(Path::toFile).toArray(File[]::new);
```

The polled folder is via ftp and is on Windows. The polling server is on linux. I also added the `iocharset=utf8` when I mounted the drive in `/etc/fstab`'s configurations.

I did not find any reference of a known issue that resembles to what I encounter.

I also tried to duplicate the environment in a docker container in order to be able to test it locally, but even though I have the same setup (the same OS, java, conf files, build, startup files, etc) I could not reproduce it. Setting the locale to UTF-8 and adding the `iocharset=utf8` parameter when mounting the drive was enough.

**So, the question is, which is the root cause of this behavior when files are containing special characters ?**

### Additional info

- The locale are set to UTF-8:

  ```
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  LANGUAGE=en_US:en
  LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  ```
- The Java process is already starting with *-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8* and *-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8* parameters.
- `ls` command inside the polled folder lists the files with their actual name, so there does not seem to be an encoding issue at the OS level

Comment: Have you tried the chatset property of the file component. I know it is used for reading and writing files but might be worth a shot. Also to clarify are you using file to read or are you using FTP? A little code could help to clearly understand it.

Comment: @Namphibian I have addded snippet code. It is from *org.apache.camel.component.file.FileConsumer.java* from Apache Camel v2.22.1.
The Linux machine is reading the file via FTP from a Windows machine.
I am not sure that it would work by setting the charset property. Even though it would work, it would imply shadowing all classes from Camel that are using the _java.io_ library. Also, I already found a solution by using the _java.nio_ package, but what I really need is to find out the root cause. Patching Camel classes may lead to other undesired behavior.